# Is "login", "log in" or "log-in" better for search engine optimization?

Tags: seo, keywords, spelling

What is the best way to phrase login for users? Is there a way to allow for the spelling of all 3 in log in link? I am debating a linked image, log in as the image text, login as the alt text and log-in as the title. I am looking at this primarily from a SEO perspective.

Comment: From a users perspective, this has an answer on UX: [Is there a difference between “login” and “log in”?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12586/is-there-a-difference-between-login-and-log-in)

Comment: I'm looking at this more from the SEO perspective. I believe that people are using login, log-in and log in equally in search and that the best SEO log in pages would have some way of highlighting all three. I am hoping to find some research along this line of thinking. SEO doesn't seem like a UX topic to me.

Comment: @gBoat, this was a different question first. You have changed the entire question so I downvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter which you use for search engines because users are not likely to be searching for them.   The keywords that matter most on your website are the ones about your subject matter.   The words that are used on most sites aren't going to bring in additional traffic.

Even if users did search for how to log in to your site, Google would likely be able to get the user to the right place no matter which you chose for your site.   Google is not as literal as it used to be and suggests pages based on synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use log-in or login for to better seo friendly url. if you have keyword like digital marketing forum and if you want to place it on url means you can use:
digital-marketing-forum and this is the perfect seo friendly url for any domain.